# How can I detect which instructions are executed on a CPU?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, cpu

Does anyone know I can detect which CPU instructions are being executed?

I am especially interested in detecting [AES instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set#New_instructions) implemented by recent Intel and AMD CPUs. Would it f.e. be possible to write a kernel module that detects these instructions? Or are the specific CPU instructions that are sent to the CPU not even known by the kernel?

Comment: It may be possible, either through processor configuration features or through debugging features, and it may require the cooperation of the kernel. This requires low-level programming knowledge, so this question would be better asked on [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time, CPUs execute processes’ instructions without involving the kernel; the kernel only has to step in if a user-level process causes a trap, either by attemptung to execute an invalid instruction (invalid here covering a variety of reasons) or by invoking a software interrupt. AES instructions are executed directly and the kernel doesn’t know that they’re being executed.

I don’t think there are any related performance counters you could use either. The AES instructions have an unusual execution pattern which *may* be identifiable statistically, but I’ve never tried that... And that’s not applicable generally anyway.

You could try using an appropriately-instrumented emulator such as [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/), or analyse binaries to determine the instructions they use — [Debian: what instructions do x86-64 binaries use?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249380/86440) has more information on the latter.